# Accessing an array within an object

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
var oldMatches = Meteor.users.find(userId, {
    fields: {
        _id: false,
        matches: true
    }
}).fetch()
```

This returns an object with an empty `matches` array, as it should. How would I access this array to find the length of it?

Thanks.

Comment: `oldMatches.matches.length`?

Comment: I've tried this with no luck.

Comment: Then `oldMatches` is not an object, like you claimed. You probably want `oldMatches[0].matches.length` then.

Comment: That is so weird! When I console log oldMatches I get [object Object] and when I run the query on the client I receive an object with an array inside... But this works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would find the length of the array with

```
oldMatches.length
```

So:

```
if(oldMatches.length) {
    // is not empty
} else {
    // is empty
}
```

N.B. `length` only works on a returned array from `fetch`, not a Meteor `cursor`

Comment: oldMatches.length gives me the length of 1, because it contains 1 array. I need the length of the array. I've tried oldMatches.matches.length, which is  what I assumed would work, but it's not.